Differentiability of a parameter dependent integral function
I want to prove the following differentiability theorem.
Theorem. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure, $f:X\times B\to \mathbb{R}$, with $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k\geq 1}$, $y_0\in B^\circ$ and suppose $f(\bullet,y)\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu), \hspace{4pt} \forall y\in B$.
Then, exists an open ball $S\subseteq B$ centered in $y_0$ and exists $g\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ such that $$|\partial_2f(x,y)|\leq g(x), \hspace{4pt} \forall y\in S$$ and almost every $x\in X$.
Under the previous hypothesis, we have:
$$\varphi: S\to \mathbb{R}, \quad \varphi(y)=\int_X f(\bullet, y)\ d\mu$$
is differentiable in $y_0$ and $$\varphi'(y_0)=\int_X \partial_2 f(\bullet, y_0) \ d\mu$$

Proof. Let's take a sequence $$(y_h)_{h\in \mathbb{N}} \hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt}y_h\overset{h}{\longrightarrow} y_0, \hspace{7pt} y_h\ne y_0, \hspace{3pt} \forall h\in \mathbb{N}$$ and consider the following ratio
$$(\ast)\quad \frac{\varphi(y_h)-\varphi(y_0)-\left(\int_E \partial_2 f(\bullet, y_0)\ d\mu\right)(y_h-y_0)}{|y_h-y_0|}$$
where $$E=\{x\in X \hspace{4pt} | \hspace{4pt} \exists \partial_2 f(x,y), \hspace{4pt}|\partial_2f(x,y)|\leq g(x), \hspace{4pt}\forall y\in S\}$$
with $\mu(X\setminus E)=0$.
I want to show that $(\ast)\longrightarrow 0$ when $h\to +\infty$.
$$(\ast)=\frac{\left|\int_E\left[f(\bullet, y_h)-f(\bullet,y_0)- \partial_2 f(\bullet, y_0)(y_h-y_0)\right]d\mu\right|}{|y_h-y_0|}$$
Because of the convergence of $(y_h)_h$, $\exists h_0\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\exists \delta>0$ such that $y_h\in S(y_0,\delta)=S, \hspace{3pt} \forall h>h_0$.
Now, using Lagrange's theorem, $\forall h>h_0, \hspace{4pt} \forall x\in E, \hspace{4pt} \exists \xi_{n,x}\in (y_0,y_h)$ such that:
$$f(\bullet,y_h)-f(\bullet,y_0)=\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})(y_h-y_0)$$
So, we have:
$$\frac{\left|\int_E\left[f(\bullet, y_h)-f(\bullet,y_0)- \partial_2 f(\bullet, y_0)(y_h-y_0)\right]d\mu\right|}{|y_h-y_0|}=$$$$=\frac{\left|\int_E\left[x\in E \mapsto \left(\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})- \partial_2 f(x, y_0)(y_h-y_0)\right)\right]d\mu\right|}{|y_h-y_0|}\leq$$
$$\leq \frac{\int_E\left|x\in E \mapsto \left(\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})- \partial_2 f(x, y_0)(y_h-y_0)\right)\right|d\mu}{|y_h-y_0|}=$$$$=\frac{\int_E\left|f(\bullet, y_h)-f(\bullet,y_0)- \partial_2 f(\bullet, y_0)(y_h-y_0)\right|d\mu}{|y_h-y_0|}$$
Now, let's study the following quantity:
$$\frac{|f(\bullet,y_h)-f(\bullet,y_0)-\partial_2 f(x,y_0)(y_h-y_0)|}{|y_h-y_0|}=\frac{\left|\left(\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})-\partial_2 f(x,y_0)\right)(y_h-y_0)\right|}{|y_h-y_0|}=\left|\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})-\partial_2 f(x,y_0)\right|$$
$\Longrightarrow \left|\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})-\partial_2 f(x,y_0)\right|\leq \left|\partial_2 f(x,\xi_{n,x})\right|+\left|\partial_2 f(x,y_0)\right|\leq 2g(x)$
So, we have that:
$$(\ast)\leq \int_E 2g\ d\mu<+\infty$$ because $g\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$.
My problem is that this proof proves that the initial incremental ratio is bounded and therefore the function $\varphi$ is differentiable in $y_0$ but I don't see how it can prove that the formula for $\varphi'(y_0)$ given that it does not I see no way that $(\ast)$ tends to zero from this discussion. Where am I getting lost? Statement and proof were done in class by my professor and so I'm a little confused.
Before, he proved that $\varphi$ is continuous with the condition $f(x,\bullet)$ continuous a.e. at $y_0$ (which I don't see how this is true from the hypothesis we have here).
Any help will be appreciated!

$$\frac{\phi(y_0+h)-\phi(y_0)}{h}=\int_X\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\mu(dx)$$
By the mean value theorem and the assumption on $\partial_xf$
$$\Big|\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\Big|=|\partial_y f(x,\xi_x)|\leq g(x)\in L_1(\mu)$$
(here $\xi_x$ is a point between $y_0$ and $y_0+h$ and depends on $x$).  Since $\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}\partial_yf(x,y_0)$, conclusion follows by direct application of dominated convergence.

Did you mean "assumption on $\partial_yf" $?

YEs, $\partial_xf$. I'll post what I wrote in my comments if that helps you. What I think might confuse you is the potential issues of measurability of $\partial_xf(x,\xi_y)$ but that is just a smokes and mirrors. What matters is the dominating bound $$\Big|\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\Big|\leq g(x)\in L_1(\mu)$$

In fact, I understand your point and I agree but what confuses me is that whole chain of equality/inequalities and then studying the integrand of the last integral. I get lost there and don't see how the dominated convergence theorem is applied. If you don't mind, could you write me a complete answer to clarify the steps in my post? I would be grateful because this proof has been driving me crazy for a week :)

Even just a general guideline of what happens, then I'll see the details myself.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your argument is correct, but I think I can be simplified considerably.
Observe that for $y_0$ in the interior of $B$, there is is $\delta>0$ such that $y_0+h$ is in the interior of $B$ whenever $|h|<\delta$.  Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\phi(y_0+h)-\phi(y_0)}{h}=\int_X\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\mu(dx)\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}
Now,
by the mean value theorem, for any $x\in X$ and $|h|<\delta$, there is $\xi_{x,h}$ between $y_0$ and $y_o+h$ such that
$$f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)=\partial_yf(x,\xi_{x,h})h$$
By the  assumption on $\partial_yf$,
\begin{align}
\Big|\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\Big|=|\partial_y f(x,\xi_{x,h})|\leq g(x)\in L_1(\mu)\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
Since $\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}\partial_yf(x,y_0)$, conclusion follows by direct application of dominated convergence.
Indeed, consider (any) sequence $h_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ and define
$G_n(x)=\frac{f(x,y_0+h_n)-f(x,y_0)}{h_n}$.
Then \eqref{zero} takes the form
$$
\frac{\phi(y_0+h_n)-\phi(y_0)}{h_n}=\int_X G_n(x)\,\mu(dx)
$$
and \eqref{one} takes the form
$$|G_n(x)|\leq g(x)\in L_1(\mu)$$
Since $\lim_nG_n(x)=\partial_yf(x,y_0)$, dominated convergence yields that
$$\lim_n\frac{\phi(y_0+h_n)-\phi(y_0)}{h_n}=\lim_n\int_X G_n(x)\,\mu(dx)=\int_X\lim_nG_n(x)\,\mu(dx)=\int_X\partial_yf(x,y_0)\mu(dx)$$

I guess in lectures your instructor did something like $$\frac{\phi(y_0+h)-\phi(y_0)}{h}-\int_X\partial_yf(x,y_0)\,d\mu=\int_X\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)-h\partial_yf(x,y_0)}{h}\,d\mu$$
Then
$$\Big|\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)-h\partial_yf(x,y_0)}{h}\Big|
=\frac{|\partial_yf(x,\xi_{x,h})h-\partial_yf(x,y_0)h|}{|h|}\leq2g(x)
$$
Then apply dominated convergence with $F_n(x)=\frac{f(x,y_0+h_n)-f(x,y_0)-h_n\partial_yf(x,y_0)}{h_n}$ which is dominated by $g(x)$  on the one hand, and on the other $F_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.  This way, you obtain
\begin{align}
\lim_n\frac{\phi(y_0+h_n)-phi(y_0)}{n}-\int_X\partial_xf(x,y_0)\,d\mu&=\lim_n\int_XF_n(x),\mu(dx)\\
&=\int_X\lim_nF_n(x)\,\mu(dx)=\int_X0\,d\mu=0
\end{align}

I don't know how to thank you,it's all clear to me so naturally now! Of course my professor made it as convoluted as possible...

@SigmaAlgebra: I guess in lectures your instructor did something like $$\frac{\phi(y_0+h)-\phi(y_0)}{h}-\int_X\partial_yf(x,y_0),d\mu=\int_X\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)-h\partial_yf(x,y_0)}{h},d\mu$$
Then
$$\Big|\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)-h\partial_yf(x,y_0)}{h}\Big|
=\frac{|\partial_yf(x,\xi_{x,h})h-\partial_yf(x,y_0)h|}{|h|}\leq2g(x)
$$
Then apply dominated convergence with $F_n(x)=\frac{f(x,y_0+h_n)-f(x,y_0)-h_n\partial_yf(x,y_0)}{h_n}$ which is dominated by $g(x)$  on the one hand, and on the other $F_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Yes, exactly! And the fact that $F_n(x)\to 0$ is given in the same way as you explained by the definition of partial derivative $\partial_2$?

Anyway, your way is much faster and clear!

YEs, notice that by definition $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}=\partial_yf(x,y_0)$ (or  equivalently $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\Big(\frac{f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0)}{h}-\partial_yf(x,y_0)\Big)=0$

Or even equivalently, in the style of my professor $$\lim_{h\to \infty}\frac{f(x,y_h)-f(x,y_0)}{|y_h-y_0|}=\partial_2f(x ,y_0 )$$ where $y_h\to y_0$ when $h\to +\infty$. Is it correct?

Just drop the absolute value in the denominator. Indeed, set $y_n=y_0+h_n$ to get $h_n=y_n-y_0$.

Perfect, you clarified all my doubts, thank you so much. I'm sorry being able to just put one upvote!!
